# How Can I Reduce Detecting the Node Failure Time on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 Slave and 1 Master node kubernetes cluster.When a node down it takes approximately 5 minutes to kubernetes see that failure.I am using dynamic provisioning for volumes and this time is a little bit much for me.How can i reduce that detecting failure time ?
I found a post about it:
https://fatalfailure.wordpress.com/2016/06/10/improving-kubernetes-reliability-quicker-detection-of-a-node-down/

At the bottom of the post,it says, we can reduce that detection time by changing that parameters:

**kubelet: node-status-update-frequency=4s (from 10s)

controller-manager: node-monitor-period=2s (from 5s)

controller-manager: node-monitor-grace-period=16s (from 40s)

controller-manager: pod-eviction-timeout=30s (from 5m)**

i can change node-status-update-frequency parameter from kubelet but i don't have any controller manager program or command on the cli.How can i change that parameters? Any other suggestions about reducing detect downtime will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> ..but i don't have any controller manager program or command on the
>   cli.How can i change that parameters?

You can change/add that parameter in `controller-manger` systemd unit file and restart the daemon. Please check the man pages for `controller-manager` [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/).

If you deploy `controller-manager` as micro service(pod), check the manifest file for that pod and change the parameters at container's `command` section(For example like [this](https://github.com/veerendra2/my-k8s-applications/blob/master/nodecellar/nodecellar-deployement.yaml#L23))

Comment: There is a manifest file could be about it: 
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml 
Can i add that flags and apply that manifest file ? Is it useful ?
kubectl apply -f kube-controller-manager.yaml

Comment: Yes, you can modify that manifest. Probably you will need to restart kubelet after that.

Comment: Unfortunately manifest file gives crashloopbackoff.I tried /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf also but it does not give any effect.
when i give describe command it shows nothing:
Back-off restarting failed container

Comment: @AdiSoyadi, what does it saying? I didnt remember exactly, can you check how those pods are deployed i.e `replicaset` or `deamonset` in `kube-system` namespace. Then open the manifest file for `replicaset`/`daemonset` and edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually **kube-controller-manager**. You may also decrease --attach-detach-reconcile-sync-period from 1m to 15 or 30 seconds for kube-controller-manager. This will allow for more speedy volumes attach-detach actions. How you change those parameters depends on how you set up the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for reply.My actual problem is i cannot find any documentation about kube-controller-manager and i do not know how to setup and how to use it.My cluster:2slavex1master on premise cluster.(virtualbox)

Comment: Hi, could you please edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml and add necessary flags as described by community @Veerendra [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/)